# Detect when cell reception is restored

Tags: android, android-broadcast

Reception may be lost as a result of moving out of coverage, switching on the airplane mode or for any other reason. I am not interested in the reason, but I just want to know when reception is restored.

Is there a intent which can be registered to fire up a broadcast receiver?

A connectivity change receiver using `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` does not seem to work for this purpose.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html). You do this using a receiver for PHONE_STATE.

In the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<receiver android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The BroadcastReceiver:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ServiceStateListener phoneListener = new ServiceStateListener();
        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        telephonyManager.listen(null, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }

}
```

The PhoneStateListener:

```
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;

class ServiceStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    public void onServiceStateChanged (ServiceState serviceState) {
        boolean connected = (serviceState.getState() == ServiceState.STATE_IN_SERVICE);
        // Do work based on "connected"
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented your solution, but the onReceive method is not triggered if I switch to flight mode, but only if the CALL_STATE changes. Any idea why?